# Javascript variable passing between function

Tags: javascript

I have the code below:

```
$("input.isDebt").click(function() {
    var totalAmount_test = $("#CC_TotalAmount_form").val();
    var total = 0;
    $("input.isDebt:checked").each(function() {
        total = parseFloat($(this).val());
        });

        totalAmount_test = parseFloat(totalAmount_test)+total;
    });
$("input.isDebt").blur(function() {
    sum = totalAmount_test + parseFloat($("#CC_TotalAmount_form").val());
    $("#CC_TotalAmount_form").val(sum.toFixed(2));


});


});
```

I need `totalAmmount_test` to be passed from the `$("input.isDebt:checked").each(function() { ... })` into the function `$("input.isDebt").blur(function() { ... })`.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: try declaring totalAmmount_test outside the click function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use `.data()` (assuming your using jQuery). More info on that [here](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$("input.isDebt").click(function() {
    var totalAmount_test = $("#CC_TotalAmount_form").val();
    var total = 0;
    $("input.isDebt:checked").each(function() {
        total = parseFloat($(this).val());
        });

        totalAmount_test = parseFloat(totalAmount_test)+total;
        $(this).data('totalAmount_test', totalAmount_test);
    });
$("input.isDebt").blur(function() {
    totalAmount_test = $(this).data('totalAmount_test');
    sum = totalAmount_test + parseFloat($("#CC_TotalAmount_form").val());
    $("#CC_TotalAmount_form").val(sum.toFixed(2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure..

```
var totalAmount_test = 0;
$("input.isDebt").click(function() {
    totalAmount_test = $("#CC_TotalAmount_form").val();
    var total = 0;
    $("input.isDebt:checked").each(function() {
        total = parseFloat($(this).val());
        });

        totalAmount_test = parseFloat(totalAmount_test)+total;
    });
$("input.isDebt").blur(function() {
    sum = totalAmount_test + parseFloat($("#CC_TotalAmount_form").val());
    $("#CC_TotalAmount_form").val(sum.toFixed(2));
});
});
```

Would be the easiest way.

Comment: I am using the code with radio buttons, it is passing the values ok but is incrementing the total. for example - I have a total of 50 and I have two radio buttons one with a value of 10 and the other with a value of 20 when I click the radio button with a value of 10 the total will become 60, this is working ok. but if I change my mind and choose the radio button with the value of 20 the total then becomes 80 instead of being 70.


I hope this makes sense to somebody

Answer (score 0):

create an element with a data attribute, make sure to prefix custom attributes with 'data-' to be HTML5 compliant

```
$("input.isDebt").click(function() {
    var totalAmount_test = $("#CC_TotalAmount_form").val();
    var total = 0;
    $("input.isDebt:checked").each(function() {
        total = parseFloat($(this).val());
        });

        totalAmount_test = parseFloat(totalAmount_test)+total;

        // creates a hidden element w/the amount
        $("<div id='total-amount' style='display:none'></div>").attr("data-total-amount", totalAmount_test); 
    });

$("input.isDebt").blur(function() {
    // retrieve the value
    var totalAmount = $("#total-amount").attr("data-total-amount"); 

    // remove the div if you don't need it anymore
    $("#total-amount").remove(); 

    sum = totalAmount_test + parseFloat($("#CC_TotalAmount_form").val());
    $("#CC_TotalAmount_form").val(sum.toFixed(2));
});


});
```